# CDF of $p(1-p)^y$

Tags: probability

I need to find the CDF for

\begin{align}
f(y) = 
\begin{cases}
p(1-p)^y,  & \text{for $y = 0, 1, 2, 3,...$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Since the sum of $ab^k$ is given as $a{1-b^{m+1}\over 1-b}$, I think that the CDF for this discrete PMF should be

$p{1-{(1-p)}^\infty\over 1-(1-p)}$

Since $0<p<1$, I think $(1-p)$ should become infinitely smaller until it is effectively zero, leaving me with

$p{1\over 1-(1-p)}$

This would simplify to $F(y)=1/p$ unless I did something wrong- did I? I always get confused working with series and sequences, especially infinite series. As an aside, does anyone have some recommendations for remedial notes on series and sequences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't reduce to $\frac 1p$ but to $1$. There is a $p$ in the numerator as well.

CDF of a function is always $1$ at $\infty$. If you want $F(y)$, sum only until $y$

$\implies f(0)+f(1)+...+f(y) \implies p\frac {1-(1-p)^{y+1}}{1-(1-p)}=1-(1-p)^{y+1}$

Answer (score 3):

$p(1-p)^y~\mathbf 1_{y\in \Bbb N}$ is the probability of obtaining exactly $y$ consecutive 'failures' *before* the first success in a sequence of iid Bernoulli trials. (AKA a Geometric($0$) distribution)

The Cumulative distribution for this would be the probability of *not* obtaining $y+1$ consecutive 'failures' before the first success.   Clearly: $1-(1-p)^{y+1}$

You can also find this through the *finite* Geometric series $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\quad y} p(1-p)^k ~=~& \sum_{k=0}^{\quad y} ar^k & \text{where}~ a= 0, r=(1-p)
\\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{a(1-r^{y+1})}{1-r}
\\[1ex] = ~& \dfrac{p~(1-(1-p)^{y+1})}{1-(1-p)}
\\[1ex] = ~& 1-(1-p)^{y+1}\end{align}$$

Thus $$\mathsf P(Y\leq y)  = \begin{cases}1-(1-p)^{y+1} &:& y\in\{0,1,2,...\}
\\ 0 &:& \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: upvote for clear explanation.